# Capture Python's shell command within the own script

Tags: python, shell

Launching a hypothetical Python script with several arguments (with argparse) from the shell, let's say, `python my_script.py --foo 7.4 --bar whatever`, I want to capture this shell command from the own script and put it in a string variable.

Of course, I could save those arguments just after doing `args = parser.parse_args()` by converting that object into a dictionary: `args_dict = vars(args)`. But I don't want that. What I want is to get the whole shell command `python my_script.py --foo 7.4 --bar whatever` as a string.

Is that possible? If not, could I still get the shell command and put it as a part of the output when saving it in a file by doing `python my_script.py --foo 7.4 --bar whatever >> my_output.txt`?

Comment: The arguments are in `sys.argv`.

Comment: To be clear, a UNIX program's argument list **isn't** a string at all. The operating system passes it as an *array* of NUL-terminated C strings, one per argument, with redirections and other shell syntax already removed (if they ever existed; programs don't need a shell to be invoked). Python puts that in `sys.argv` -- it's all the information the OS gives your Python interpreter, so it's all the information that's available.

Comment: Is there a shell command that will give you the shell's command history? If so you could execute that.

Comment: @wwii, ...of course, this requires a bunch of assumptions, that your program was started by an interactive shell with history expansion enabled for one; that that shell was configured to save history before starting each command for another.

Comment: @wwii I didn't think about it. Yeah, I have the history expansion enabled. I'll try that and, if I'm successful, I'll post it. Many thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly accurate, but you can infer it like this:

```py
import sys

print ("%s %s" % (sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv) ) )
```

```sh
❯ python3 test.py --foo 7.4 --bar=whatever
/usr/bin/python3 test.py --foo 7.4 --bar=whatever
```

This will not catch pipes and the likes, only the command invoking python:

```sh
❯ python3 test.py | cat
/usr/bin/python3 test.py
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. The only solution is to try to infer it manually. But, as you said, it doesn't catch pipes and those sort of things. For example, I normally measure the execution time and save the screen output in a file by doing ` time python my_script.py --foo 7.4 --bar whatever >> my_output.txt`. That's a shame but thanks to all anyway